# Composite C1 - Language / Localization in Blog module

Tags: c1-cms

I have added a second language, French, to a Composite C1 site (System/Languages/Add Language).

It works fine for content pages when I select the language (bottom right).

However - blogs do not have this option. How can I add languages to blog posts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, enable localization on the Blog's data types:

- Composite.Community.Blog.Authors
- Composite.Community.Blog.Tags
- Composite.Community.Blog.Entries

For this:

In the Data perspective:

1. select each of the data types
2. click Enable Localization on the tool bar
3. and follow the wizard to finish the task

Next, translate tags and athors:

In the Content perspective / Website Items / Blog Settings:

1. select data items below Authors and Tags
2. click Translate on the toolbar to create a language copy of the item
3. Then translate it

Finally, translate the blog posts likewise

1. Expand the blog page, then Blog entries, then the date folder
2. select a blog post
3. cick Translate on the toolbar
4. then actually translate the post to your language

Comment: Thanks. I added localization in the blogs datatypes. However, when I go to Blog Settings/Authors or Tags, clicking each tag/author there is no localization option (also can i Just not localize authors?)

Comment: Have you switched the languages? You can "translate" and then edit the items of those data types in the other language (not the default one wher you originally created the blog).